# Android notify the user at a later time

Tags: android, notifications, usability, user-experience

I want to create an application in android in which the user selects a certain day in the future and then, when that day arrives he will get a notification (I know that this can be done through the Calendar or the notes but that doesn't matter in my case).

I have two problems concerting the previous:

a. How should I implement the notification ? I read elsewhere about adding events to the Google Calendar of the user - but that is not standard. Should I implement a service that checks to see if that day has arrived and add the notificatin ?

b. As I wrote, I care about day only, and not time. This generates the following problem for me: When should I notify the user in order to not bother him ? When the application knows only the day of the notification (and not the time) then how can it determine at what time in that day to actually notify the user ? What if the user is asleep ? Is it possible to add a "silent" notification so that the user won't be bothered ?

TIA,
Serafeim

Comment: Tutorial: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both problems are solved by a 'status bar notification'

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

You can add a sound to this to alert the user.

If the user is 'asleep' i.e. the phone is on silent I believe the notification won't make a sound.

A notification does not need a time of day as you can 'notify' at the very start of the day and the user will see it when they first check there phone that day, so time is irrelevant.

You will have a service that runs to check the data yes, then start this notification. It may be possible to have an event listener for some given event that would start your service that would then check the date, and if so post your notification!

Here is my tutorial on this:
http://blog.blundellapps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Enjoy!

Comment: So, I should implement a service in order to add the notification at a later time ? Concerning the user experience, I'd really like to be able to add a 'silent' notification even when the phone is not silent. If you do actually write the tutorial about notifications - services etc please post a link here :)

Comment: Hmmm after checking http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_SOUND I think that I know how to make a silent notification: Just set DEFAULT_SOUND flag to 0 and leave the sound field of the notification empty !

Comment: Yeah you can set the sound to off. Sure I will do, started it last night taking longer than I expected :-) looking at the AlarmManager, otherwise the service may be killed when your phone is turned off