# Notification at later time and daily

Tags: java, android

I want my application to notify me once at 3 am in the morning then at 7 pm in the evening then 3.01 am in the morning and 7.01 pm in the evening and so on. My code for just one notification is

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(), 0);
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(2014, Calendar.JUNE, 27, 4, 0);
  long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
  Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
    "Testing...", startTime);
  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
  notif.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.glass);
  notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500 };

  nm.notify(1, notif);
```

Now even when I do this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2014, Calendar.JUNE, 27, 4, 0);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

I get notification at current time, for example, it is 4 pm now and I set notification of 7 pm, when I run the app then it notifies me very next second i.e. 4pm.

I have seen these links and they are doing same but for Alarm.

[Android notify the user at a later time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284106/android-notify-the-user-at-a-later-time)
http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

1. I am having problem in setting up notification for a later time?
2. I want to notify user daily, twice a day. How can I achieve this? (If I cant achieve this with notification then let me know how to achieve this with alarm.)

Thanks